# How to run NodeJS unit tests with a different NODE_PATH

Tags: node.js, jasmine, gulp

### The question

Can I run unit tests from within Node/Gulp which have a different NODE_PATH than what has been inherited from the environment?

### The issue

I have a project which is being run from within a Rhino based application, where `require` loads scripts from a set of defined locations.

I want to have unit tests for my components. In order to run those tests I need to be able to call my scripts from the Node environment. But that ends with error similar to this:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'lib/foo/foo.js'
```

This is because my scripts contain `require(foo/foo)`... that would be fine if `NODE_PATH` would have contained `lib`. The issue here is that I only want this folder to be present for unit tests, not for other gulp tasks.

---

I guess the issue I am facing is that all *test runners* I came across (e.g. *karma*) are browser based. So my question might as well be: *Is there a test runner which runs pure NodeJS tests?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have invested a few hours into finding answer to my question. Node is [quite](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2234) [hostile](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1773) when it comes to manipulating `NODE_PATH` during runtime.

So the answer to my own question is: **No, gulp-based tests can not run with a different `NODE_PATH`, unless those tests [spawn a new process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).**

---

I was not able to find convenient test runner which is able to spawn *node* with a different environment. I was able to write my own code to run unit tests in a new process, but that had far too many "rough edges".

**In the end I went for [app-module-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-module-path) module to keep things simple** (I didn't want a special wrapper shell script). That is not exactly what I was looking for, but it is pretty close.

Comment: I haven't been able to make app-module-path work with ES6 code transpiled through Babel --- it hoists the module imports above any other code, so the app-module-path invocation always happens after the modules are required.

Comment: Actually, my previous comment, which is just too late to edit, is wrong --- you can make this work. You need to create a shim module containing the `require("app-module-path").addPath(__dirname + "/....");` line. Then you import that from your ES6 file. This will get loaded and executed before any other modules are imported, which means the path is set up correctly and everything works.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can always do something along the lines of

```
NODE_PATH=NODE_PATH:/path/to/lib npm test`.
```

`NODE_PATH` is just an environment variable. Usually you rely on the value that persists through login shell profile. But you can set/unset/change it as it suits you.

To set an environment variable just for the duration of execution of this one command...

```
VARIABLE=VALUE command <args...>
```

To set an environment variable for the duration of your shell session i.e. until you exit/logout or reset the shell...

```
export VARIABLE=VALUE
command <args...>
```

To make it persist through shell sessions, you will have to add `export VARIBALE=VALUE` to your

`.bashrc` or
`.bash_profile` or
`/etc/profile` or
a file inside `/etc/profile.d/`

depending on your preference and your environment.

**Edit:** I have made an unfair assumption that you are using Linux or Mac. I apologize if that is not the case. For Windows, you can do something like

```
%NODE_PATH%=%NODE_PATH%;\path\to\lib\
```

or something. You can also go to *System Properties -> Advanced Settings -> Environment Variables* and set/unset/change globally persistent environment variables there.

**Edit #2:** Refactored for clarity.

Comment: Your answer turned to *"what are environment variables and how to use them"*, which is not the core of the question. Even more - this is explicitly stated as not a solution in the question itself.

Comment: @PavelHoral I sincerely apologize. Although I read the question a number of times before answering it, for some reason I failed to take in the *"want this folder to be present for unit tests, not for other gulp tasks"* part.

Comment: Could you take a look at your first command?  I'm not sure exactly  what it's trying to say, but it's not valid bash syntax-- it seems to have an unmatched backquote and is maybe missing a $.